# Is there a way to change the System User Agent of Genymotion Emulator?

Tags: android, request, emulation, genymotion

I have a question regarding Genymotion Android Emulator:

Is there a way to change the system User Agent which is used in every HTTP Request for every app?

Mine looks like this:

```
Genymotion Google Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.2 - API 17 - 720x1280
```

I'd like to get that "Genymotion" removed, because it's causing troubles with some apps. Is there a way to do that somehow?